# Load balancing long lived sessions that require server state

Tags: http, session-state, load-balancing

Suppose a user's session is load balanced to server #8 and some state is maintained at server #8. The next action from user needs to be routed to server #8 again because that is the only place with his server state. Is there a standard solution to maintain this mapping from user session to server number for long lived sessions? It seems like this problem of mapping user session to a specific server among many servers should be a common problem with a standard "textbook" solution thats cpu and memory efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is not to rely on server affinity - it makes your system fragile. I wouldn't expect a textbook answer in the same way I would not expect a textbook answer on how to play with a toaster in the bath nor how to perform brain surgery with a screwdriver.

If you must have sticky routing then how you implement it depends a lot on how you propose to deal with a server not being available - do you failover the requests? Or just stop processing requests which would have been directed to that server?

I initially thought that this was a very dumb question - what's the relevance unless you're writing your own proxy/load-balancer (in which case you should already know he answers) but there are proxies available which allow you to implement your own director.

So ultimately it boils down to what characteristics of the session are visible in the HTTP request. Since an IP adderss can change mid stream, the only practical characteristic you can use is the session idenitifier - usually implemented as a cookie.

Comment: Consider 10 backend servers. Fault tolerance is achieved by replicating each of those servers 3 times.

Suppose you have a poker service. Then you must maintain server state. Each poker hand must be maintained on some server since you can't trust clients with the state. So the need to rely on server maintaining state isn't so unusual after all.

Comment: No - the session data does not have top be tied to a particular node in a cluster.

Comment: So how would you maintain the state of each poker hand?

Comment: In the session data. Where else?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. How can the full data not be on server if I'm trying to prevent the clients from manipulating the hand.

Comment: You should **never** store session data on the client. The session data must be **available** to a server. It does **not** have to be stored **on the server and nowhere else**

Comment: Can you be specific about what the cookie will exactly look like and how the server will exactly process the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to configure your load balancer to use sticky sessions.  the load balancer will associate a user session to Server #8, and then subsequent requests from the same session will automatically be forwarded to the same server (Server 8).